# SwiftUI How to not duplicate ViewModel in List

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I have simple 2 screens app. First screen is the `List`, second is detailed screen.

It's obvious I don't need 20 detailed screens, same as number of items in the `List`, but only one.

I need pass selected item as parameter to `ViewModel` of the detailed screen. I know two options implement this:

1. Create for each `NavigationLink` new `ViewModel(selectededItem: Item)`
2. Pass it through `EnvironmentObject`, but it's also bad solution, because first I need some how do like `viewModel.selectedItem = item`

My current implementation. It duplicates view models, also very important question is - does SwiftUI create copy of new view for each navigation link as well as view model?

```
List(viewModel.state.subCategory) { subCategory in
    HStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: {
            ProductsListBuilder.build(id: subCategory.id ?? -1)
        }, label: {
            Text(subCategory.title ?? "no name")
        })
    }
}
```

---

```
class ProductsListBuilder {
    static func build(id: Int) -> some View {
        let viewModel = ProductsViewModel(dataFetcher: RemoteDataProviderImpl.shared, productId: id)
        return ProductsListView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Make sure you show what your `ProductsListView` is. You do not need the `ProductsListBuilder`. I would also go through [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) and [Stanford's CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases you can use `LazyView`:

```
struct LazyView<Content: View>: View {
    let build: () -> Content
    init(_ build: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.build = build
    }
    var body: Content {
        build()
    }
}
```

It makes `build` to only be called when the navigation link is actually opened:

```
NavigationLink(destination: LazyView(
    ProductsListBuilder.build(id: subCategory.id ?? -1)
), label: {
    Text(subCategory.title ?? "no name")
})
```